# Why solar cells have a wind speed meter?

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy

I saw some solar cells in rooftop of a governmental office that were there for providing 220V Ac current for the office's lights and low consuming electrical devices.
one of the cells had a wind speed meter like the image below:(it only had a speed meter , not a wind direction sensor in the right side of the image)

[image: wind meter]

And a fuse box was installed on that cell.
also there was an astronomical clock in the way of wires that were connecting the cells output to the office.

My question is why solar cells need astronomical clock and a wind speed meter?

Comment: they do not need those things .... in that installation, the panels may be remotely movable .... the astronomical clock may be used to track the sun ... the windspeed sensor would determine if the panels need to be laid flat against the roof if the wind speed is too high ...... but `solar cells do not need astronomical clock and a wind speed meter`

Comment: Why assume that the wind speed was for the solar panels ? Perhaps they have a weather display and that was a handy place to mount it...

Comment: @jsotola there are cheaper methods to track the sun than an astronomical clock...

Comment: what kind of an astronomical clock did you see at the office? ... are you sure it was one? .... maybe it was just a timer

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the Photo Voltaic cells and the anemometer are independent of each other. They are just monitoring windspeed and direction for their own purposes, like potentially putting up a wind turbine perhaps. Who knows why, but one does not need the other. By the way, as I don't know your knowledge level on these things, Solar cells produce DC Voltage only, and must go through a DC to AC inverter to be of use to common wall supplied appliances. This piece of equipment is complex and expensive.

Comment: The OP said they did not have a wind direction sensor...but +1 anyway.

Comment: OOPS, should have paid more attention, Time for bed. : )

Comment: There is such a thing as a motorized solar panel rack that tracks the Sun on good-weather days, and which lays the panels flat to reduce the risk of wind damage on stormy days. A stationary rack is cheaper, and more robust—not as likely to be damaged by storms—but a motorized system can harvest considerably more energy per day for a given footprint. It can be worth the extra up-front $$$ when only limited space is available for the installation.

Answer (score 1):

People are saying they are independent of each other, but I don't think they are.  I'm seeing a lot of solar tracker systems on Ebay and other websites which come with an anemometer.  I believe it's used in solar tracking somehow, but I don't know know how.  I was searching for it on Google and that brought me here.  So while this isn't the perfect answer, I just wanted to clear up that other answers may be wrong when saying the 2 are unrelated.